# leapmotion gesture cast to swipeGesture

Tags: leap-motion

I want to make sign language program with leap motion.
when I stretch my arm, it means 'enter sign language'.
when I swipe right with left hand, it means 'space'.
swipe left with right hand means 'backspace'.

I should cognize the frame has gesture or not.
I did it by counting frame.gestures.
Is it right?

```
    public void onFrame(Controller controller) {
            Frame frame = controller.frame();
            String sDirection = "";
            GestureList gestures = frame.gestures();

            if (gestures.count() == 0) {
                try{
                    run(controller);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                sDirection = gesture(gestures);
            }
            System.out.println(sDirection);

        }
```

when detect gesture, function gesture work.
I only need swipe gesture.

```
        public String gesture(GestureList gestures) {
                String result = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < gestures.count(); i++) {

        if (gestures.get(i).type() == Gesture.Type.TYPE_SWIPE) {

            SwipeGesture vSwipe = (SwipeGesture) gestures.get(i);///What's wrong?!!!!!!!
            System.out.println(gestures.get(i).type()); //
            // Compare directions and give preference to the greatest linear
            // movement.
            float fAbsX = Math.abs(vSwipe.direction().getX());
            float fAbsY = Math.abs(vSwipe.direction().getY());
            float fAbsZ = Math.abs(vSwipe.direction().getZ());

                    .....
```

in function gesture,

SwipeGesture vSwipe = (SwipeGesture) gestures.get(i); -> didn't work.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Casting isn't supported. You need to create a new SwipeGesture object from the Gesture object:

```
SwipeGesture vSwipe = SwipeGesture(gestures.get(i));
```